# postgresql trigger NEW row as a json

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am writing a trigger where I need to convert NEW row into a json and insert into an other table. I am not getting it right.

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.eventlogs_add_user()
      RETURNS trigger AS

    $BODY$
    DECLARE newRecord JSON;
    BEGIN

    newRecord :=  row_to_json(row)
        from (NEW) row;


// Insert newRecord into another table


    RETURN NEW;
    END$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION public.eventlogs_add_user()
      OWNER TO postgres;

    -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: new is already row - you should be able to `row_to_json(NEW.*)` ?..

Comment: what's the problem, error message, issue?

Comment: row_to_json(NEW) has worked thanks

Comment: I really wish this had a more robust subsequent INSERT. I want to to pretty much the same, but then pick properties out of *newRecord*, say like "first_name" and "age" or something... But, Postgres won't allow my function with json operators. Like: `newRecord->>'first_name'` I can't even save the function when attempting to use these operators.

Answer (score 13):

changing

```
newRecord :=  row_to_json(row)
        from (NEW) row;
```

to

```
newRecord :=  row_to_json(NEW.*);
```

should help

Comment: @alowsarwar Did I answer your question?

Comment: I see this is an older answer, and I suspect it worked. Could you elaborate and say how you would then pick individual properties out of this variable `newRecord`? I can't successfully run and store any function using JSON operators inside. No `->  ->>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

since Trigger.NEW is already a row
you should try passing it as is to row_to_json

like

```
row_to_json(NEW)
```